# How to show elements of array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a small problem. I created a large array.
It looks like this:

```
var Array = [ 
["text10", "text11", ["text01", "text02"]], 
["text20", "text21", ["text11", "text12"]] 
]
```

If we write this way: Array[0] that shows all the elements.

If we write this way: Array[0][0] that shows "text1".

If we write this way: Array[0][2] that shows

> -2 elements
>
> -- 0: "text01"
>
> -- 1: "text02"
> .

If we write this way: Array[0][2].count or Array[0][2][0] it will not work
How do I choose each item, I need these elements for the tableView

Comment: change Array to array and make print(array). It will show all the content

Comment: Using array inside an array is an anti-pattern, and you should avoid that if possible. Could you explain what's the content of your array? Maybe we could refactor your code into struct or class.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I think he wants to use the array in the table view, not printing it.

Comment: @EdwardAnthony well, he wrote 'If we write this way: Array[0][2] that shows' so I think whatever the ultimate purpose is the questioner would like to at least print the contents of the array

Comment: Your array is invalid it should be same type either array or string it will become [[Any]] So  Array[0][2].count will not work !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @matt already answered but I want to add this thing

**Why Array[0][2].count or Array[0][2][0]  not work**

If you Define array

```
var array = [
    ["text10", "text11", ["text01", "text02"]],
    ["text20", "text21", ["text11", "text12"]]
]
```

And when you type array you can see it's type  is **[[Any]]** However it contains `String` as well as `Array`

[image]

So When you try to get  `Array[0][2]` Swift does not know that your array at position 2 has another array which can have count

**EDIT**

What you are asking now is Array of dictionary I suggest you to go with model i.e create struct or class and use it instead of dictionary

Now If you want to create dictionary then

```
var arrOfDict = ["text10" :  ["text01", "text02"] , "text11" :  ["text11", "text12"]]
```

And you can access with key name  `let arrayatZero = arrOfDict["text10"] as? [String]`

Answer (score 2):

The problem basically is that your inner array is illegal. Swift arrays must consist of elements of a single type. You have two types of element, String and Array Of String. Swift tries to compensate but the result is that double indexing can’t work, not least because there is no way to know whether a particular element will have a String or an Array in it.

The solution is to rearchitect completely. If your array entries all consist of the same pattern String plus String plus Array of String, then the pattern tells you what to do; that should be a custom struct, not an array at all.